# Problema de permissão ao instalar MediaWiki no Sql Server

Tags: sql-server, mediawiki

Estou tendo problemas ao tentar instalar a MediaWiki usando Sql Server.

Ocorre o seguinte erro:

> [SQLSTATE 42000][Error Code 2760][Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]The specified schema name "dbo" either does not exist or you do not have permission to use it. [SQLSTATE 42000][Error Code 2759][Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]CREATE SCHEMA failed due to previous errors.

[image: Print do erro MediaWiki + Sql Server]

O erro acontece usando tanto as contas `Windows authentication` como o `sa` em **User account for installation**.

Nota: mesmo após esse erro, a tabela que defini é criada.

O que posso fazer quanto a isso?

Answer (score -6):

O erro que você está enfrentando ao tentar instalar o MediaWiki com o SQL Server indica que o schema "dbo" especificado não existe ou você não tem permissão para usá-lo. Isso geralmente ocorre quando o usuário ou a conta de serviço que você está usando não tem as permissões necessárias no banco de dados do SQL Server.

Para resolver esse problema, siga estas etapas:

Verifique as Permissões do Usuário:

Certifique-se de que o usuário ou a conta de serviço que você está usando para conectar ao SQL Server tenha permissões suficientes para criar schemas e tabelas no banco de dados. O usuário deve ter pelo menos a permissão CREATE SCHEMA.
Verifique o Banco de Dados:

Verifique se o banco de dados que você está tentando usar com o MediaWiki já existe. Se ele não existir, você pode criar um banco de dados usando o SQL Server Management Studio (ou outra ferramenta de gerenciamento) e atribuir permissões adequadas ao seu usuário.
Use um Schema Existente (Opcional):

Se você já tem um schema existente que deseja usar em vez do "dbo", certifique-se de que o schema exista no banco de dados e que você tenha permissões para usá-lo. Você pode especificar o schema nas configurações de conexão do MediaWiki.
Verifique a Configuração do MediaWiki:

Verifique se a configuração do MediaWiki está correta. Verifique o arquivo LocalSettings.php para garantir que as configurações de conexão ao banco de dados estejam configuradas corretamente, incluindo o nome do banco de dados, o nome do servidor SQL Server, o nome de usuário e a senha.
Execute o Script de Instalação do MediaWiki novamente:

Se você fez alterações nas permissões do SQL Server ou na configuração do banco de dados, pode ser necessário reexecutar o script de instalação do MediaWiki para criar as tabelas e schemas necessários.
Verifique Logs de Erro:

Consulte os logs de erro do SQL Server e do MediaWiki para obter informações mais detalhadas sobre o problema. Isso pode ajudar a identificar a causa raiz do erro.
Lembre-se de que a solução exata pode variar dependendo da sua configuração específica do SQL Server e do MediaWiki, mas essas etapas devem ajudá-lo a resolver o erro relacionado ao schema "dbo". Certifique-se de ter backups adequados antes de fazer qualquer alteração significativa em seu banco de dados.